# Angular Reactive Form form status with asynchronous events

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-changedetection

Why Angular **PatchValue()** method make the form dirty when value patching is done asynchronously? I am using **primeNg** data table and listening for it's **onRowSelectionChange** event.

```
 this.cityGrid.onRowSelectionChange.subscribe(event => 
  this.rowSelectionChange(event));

  public rowSelectionChange(selectedEntry: City) {
     this.cityForm.patchValue(
      {
        m06_id: this.selectedCity.m06_id,
        m06_name: this.selectedCity.m06_name,
        m06_name_lang: this.selectedCity.m06_name_lang
      });
    }
```

After patchValue, form becomes dirty. Can anyone suggest what is going on here?

Comment: it's dirty because you updated it, where is inconsistency?

Comment: But it doesn't change it's status to dirty when patching is done in ngOnInit()

Comment: how do you test it? show some code